# Writing to segment in x86

Tags: assembly, system, x86, memory-segmentation

I would like to test how the hardware behaves in case I am trying to write into a segment ( for example a data segment other than DS maybe GS  ) just for testing purpose ... Is there an assembly instruction that allow me to specify a segment wit.h an offset and directly write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a specific segment, you have to first load the segment number into a segment register and then do a load with an appropriate segment prefix. For example, to access `0x1234:0x5678`, you can do something like this (in AT&T-syntax):

```
push $0x1234
pop %es
mov %es:0x5678,%eax
```

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl for the replay, but I am still confused about 1 thing. Isnt the mov instruction just will update the segment register with the new selector, I mean what is the diffrence if I made this (mov %es , %eax) from doing it with a prefeix?  Is using a prefeix actually write inside the segment ? Cause I basically want to write inside the segment it self not just update the segment reg. with a new selector.

Comment: @user2628079 The first instruction pushes a value on the stack, the second instruction loads this value into the segment register. This is because there is no instruction `mov $0x1234,%es`. The third instruction fetched four bytes at addres `0x5678` in the segment described by `%es` and stores them in `%eax`. Note that I'm using AT&T-syntax here. If you are more familiar with Intel syntax, I can update the example to use Intel syntax.